# How do I get all option value id's for a given attribute in a specific category in my custom block?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, attribute-options

- My shop has an attribute `manufacturer`.
- This attribute has option values like `adidas` and `nike` etc.
- I have a custom module with a block
- I placed the block on a specific category through a widget
- The category has several products assigned to it
- The products each have an attribute value set to it (`adidas` and `nike` etc.)

**How can I retrieve all the option value ID's (for `adidas` and `nike` etc.) in my custom block for the category which is currently loaded?**

Comment: Are you looking for product collection with category and attribute filter right?

Comment: No, I just want a list of the attribute option value ID's

Comment: $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

Comment: \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
$this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This retrieves all the option values in the system. I only want the one assigned to the current category I am in. So this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: check below code, may be it would help for your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 protected $eavConfig;
 protected $_productCollectionFactory;
 protected $_registry;
 public function __construct(
        ...
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
       ) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->_registry = $registry;        
        }
```

If your requirement for multple category then pass category ids in below product collections.

Use below code in your function.

```
        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        $ids = $category->getId();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $ids]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',  ['neq' => 'NULL']);
        $collection->getSelect()->group('manufacturer'); 
        $categoryoptions = $collection->getColumnValues('manufacturer');        
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();        
        $optionsExists = array();
        foreach($options as $option)
        {
            if(in_array($option['value'] , $categoryoptions))
            {
                $optionsExists[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($optionsExists);
        die();
```